# Promise<Version> through JSONException

Tags: java, jira

I have the following code with which I'm trying to get all my versions from jira with a jira API:

```
  Promise<Version> version = client.getVersionRestClient().getVersion(URI.create(jiraUrl+"/jira02/rest/api/2/project/CREDIT/versions"));
  System.out.println(version.claim());
```

This code thow me an exception that I don't understand:

```
Caused by: org.codehaus.jettison.json.JSONException: A JSONObject text must begin with '{' at character 1 of [{"self":"https://dbatlas.db.com/jira02/rest/api/2/version/22096","id":"22096","description":"June 08 Release","name":"Credit 2013.3","archived":true,"released":true,"releaseDate":"2013-06-08","userReleaseDate":"08/Jun/13","projectId":14501},{"self":"https://dbatlas.db.com/jira02/rest/api/2/version/22114","id":"22114","description":"July 20 Release","name":"Credit 2013.4","archived":true,"released":true,"releaseDate":"2013-07-20","userReleaseDate":"20/Jul/13","projectId":14501},{"self":"https://dbatlas.db.com/jira02/rest/api/2/version/22116","id":"22116","description":"Candidates for 20 July Release","name":"Credit Candidates for 2013.4","archived":true,"released":true,"releaseDate":"2013-07-20","userReleaseDate":"20/Jul/13","projectId":14501},{"self":"https://dbatlas.db.com/jira02/rest/api/2/version/22115","id":"22115","description":"Candidates for 24 Aug Release","name":"Credit Candidates for 2013.5","archived":true,"released":true,"releaseDate":"2013-08-24","userReleaseDate":"24/Aug/13","projectId":14501},{"self":"https://dbatlas.db.com/jira02/rest/api/2/version/22117","id":"22117","description":"Aug 24 Release","name":"Credit 2013.5 (9.3)","archived":true,"released":true,"releaseDate":"2013-08-31","userReleaseDate":"31/Aug/13","projectId":14501},{"self":"https://dbatlas.db.com/jira02/rest/api/2/version/27602","id":"27602","description":"2013.5 Patch Release","name":"Credit 2013.5.ex1","archived":true,"released":true,"startDate":"2013-09-03","releaseDate":"2013-09-07","userStartDate":"03/Sep/13","userReleaseDate":"07/Sep/13","projectId":14501},{"self":"https://dbatlas.db.com/jira02/rest/api/2/version/27628","id":"27628","description":"Candidates for 2013.5.SEF Release","name":"Credit Candidates for 2013.5.SEF","archived":true,"released":true,"releaseDate":"2013-09-20","userReleaseDate":"20/Sep/13","projectId":14501},{"self":"https://dbatlas.db.com/jira02/rest/api/2/version/27018","id":"27018","description":"BBG Support for CDS SEFs","name":"Credit 2013.5.SEF (9.3.1)","archived":true,"released":true,"startDate":"2013-08-19","releaseDate":"2013-09-28","userStartDate":"19/Aug/13","userReleaseDate":"28/Sep/13","projectId":14501},{"self":"https://dbatlas.db.com/jira02/rest/api/2/version/28961","id":"28961","description":"Candidates for Patch after SEF release","name":"Credit 2013.5 SEF PATCH Candidates","archived":true,"released":true,"releaseDate":"2013-10-10","userReleaseDate":"10/Oct/13","projectId":14501},{"self":"https://dbatlas.db.com/jira02/rest/api/2/version/29001","id":"29001","description":"Credit 2013.5 SEF PATCH (9.3.2) release","name":"Credit 2013.5 SEF PATCH (9.3.2)","archived":true,"released":true,"startDate":"2013-09-30","releaseDate":"2013-10-12","userStartDate":"30/Sep/13","userReleaseDate":"12/Oct/13","projectId":14501},{"self":"https://dbatlas.db.com/jira02/rest/api/2/version/22740","id":"22740","description":"Candidates for 2013.6 Release","name":"Credit Candidates for 2013.6","archived":true,"released":true,"releaseDate":"2013-10-18","userReleaseDate":"18/Oct/13","projectId":14501},{"self":"https://dbatlas.db.com/jira02/rest/api/2/version/22255","id":"22255","description":"Credit 2013.6 release","name":"Credit 2013.6 (9.4)","archived":true,"released":true,"releaseDate":"2013-10-26","userReleaseDate":"26/Oct/13","projectId":14501},{"self":"https://dbatlas.db.com/jira02/rest/api/2/version/29842","id":"29842","description":"[2013.6.ex1] TSAR patch release","name":"Credit 2013.6.ex1 [TSAR]","archived":true,"released":true,"startDate":"2013-10-28","releaseDate":"2013-10-30","userStartDate":"28/Oct/13","userReleaseDate":"30/Oct/13","projectId":14501},{"self":"https://dbatlas.db.com/jira02/rest/api/2/version/29863","id":"29863","description":"[2013.6.ex2] QTE 9.4.1 patch release","name":"Credit 2013.6.ex2 [QTE]","archived":true,"released":true,"startDate":"2013-10-30","releaseDate":"2013-11-02","userStartDate":"30/Oct/13","userReleaseDate":"02/Nov/13","projectId":14501},{"self":"https://dbatlas.db.com/jira02/rest/api/2/version/29996","id":"29996","description":"[2013.6.ex3] NB 9.4.1 patch release","name":"Credit 2013.6.ex3 [NB]","archived":true,"released":true,"startDate":"2013-11-01","releaseDate":"2013-11-16","userStartDate":"01/Nov/13","userReleaseDate":"16/Nov/13","projectId":14501},{"self":"https://dbatlas.db.com/jira02/rest/api/2/version/22741","id":"22741","description":"Candidates for 2013.7 Release","name":"Credit Candidates for 2013.7","archived":true,"released":true,"releaseDate":"2013-11-22","userReleaseDate":"22/Nov/13","projectId":14501},{"self":"https://dbatlas.db.com/jira02/rest/api/2/version/30095","id":"30095","description":"Candidates for 2013.8 Release","name":"Credit Candidates for 2013.8","archived":true,"released":true,"releaseDate":"2013-12-04","userReleaseDate":"04/Dec/13","projectId":14501},{"self":"https://dbatlas.db.com/jira02/rest/api/2/version/22256","id":"22256","description":"Credit 2013.7 release","name":"Credit 2013.7 (9.5)","archived":true,"released":true,"releaseDate":"2013-11-23","userReleaseDate":"23/Nov/13","projectId":14501},{"self":"https://dbatlas.db.com/jira02/rest/api/2/version/28504","id":"28504","description":"Credit BBG Direct clearing on ICE","name":"Credit 2013.8 (9.6)","archived":true,"released":true,"releaseDate":"2013-12-14","userReleaseDate":"14/Dec/13","projectId":14501},{"self":"https://dbatlas.db.com/jira02/rest/api/2/version/31982","id":"31982","description":"[2014.0.ex1] EMPIRE 9.6.1 Patch Release","name":"Credit 2014.0.ex1 [EMPIRE]","archived":true,"released":true,"startDate":"2013-12-25","releaseDate":"2014-01-18","userStartDate":"25/Dec/13","userReleaseDate":"18/Jan/14","projectId":14501},{"self":"https://dbatlas.db.com/jira02/rest/api/2/version/29610","id":"29610","description":"EMIR Backloading (25-Jan-14)","name":"Credit EMIR Backloading (25-Jan-14)","archived":true,"released":true,"releaseDate":"2014-02-08","userReleaseDate":"08/Feb/14","projectId":14501},{"self":"https://dbatlas.db.com/jira02/rest/api/2/version/31157","id":"31157","description":"2014.1 release (22-Feb-14)","name":"Credit 2014.1","archived":true,"released":true,"startDate":"2013-12-02","releaseDate":"2014-02-22","userStartDate":"02/Dec/13","userReleaseDate":"22/Feb/14","projectId":14501},{"self":"https://dbatlas.db.com/jira02/rest/api/2/version/32649","id":"32649","description":"Credit 2014.1.1 (01-Mar-14) Technical release","name":"Credit 2014.1.1","archived":true,"released":true,"releaseDate":"2014-03-01","userReleaseDate":"01/Mar/14","projectId":14501},{"self":"https://dbatlas.db.com/jira02/rest/api/2/version/32650","id":"32650","description":"Candidates for 2014.3 Release","name":"Credit Candidates for 2014.3","archived":true,"released":true,"projectId":14501},{"self":"https://dbatlas.db.com/jira02/rest/api/2/version/22257","id":"22257","description":"2014.3 release (12-Apr-14)","name":"Credit 2014.3","archived":true,"released":true,"releaseDate":"2014-04-12","userReleaseDate":"12/Apr/14","projectId":14501},{"self":"https://dbatlas.db.com/jira02/rest/api/2/version/27903","id":"27903","description":"Candidates for 2014.4 Release","name":"Credit Candidates for 2014.4","archived":true,"released":true,"releaseDate":"2014-04-26","userReleaseDate":"26/Apr/14","projectId":14501},{"self":"https://dbatlas.db.com/jira02/rest/api/2/version/29154","id":"29154","description":"2014.4 release (26-Apr-14)","name":"Credit 2014.4","archived":true,"released":true,"releaseDate":"2014-04-26","userReleaseDate":"26/Apr/14","projectId":14501},{"self":"https://dbatlas.db.com/jira02/rest/api/2/version/35932","id":"35932","description":"EMPIRE patch release 2014.4.1","name":"Credit 2014.4.1","archived":true,"released":true,"releaseDate":"2014-05-24","userReleaseDate":"24/May/14","projectId":14501},{"self":"https://dbatlas.db.com/jira02/rest/api/2/version/35601","id":"35601","description":"EMIR Backloading (14-Jun-14)","name":"Credit 2014.4 EMIR","archived":true,"released":true,"releaseDate":"2014-06-14","userReleaseDate":"14/Jun/14","projectId":14501},{"self":"https://dbatlas.db.com/jira02/rest/api/2/version/32129","id":"32129","description":"Candidates for 2014.5 Release","name":"Credit Candidates for 2014.5","archived":true,"released":false,"projectId":14501},{"self":"https://dbatlas.db.com/jira02/rest/api/2/version/32140","id":"32140","description":"2014.5 release (21-Jun-14)","name":"Credit 2014.5","archived":true,"released":true,"releaseDate":"2014-06-21","userReleaseDate":"21/Jun/14","projectId":14501},{"self":"https://dbatlas.db.com/jira02/rest/api/2/version/36689","id":"36689","description":"2014.5 patch release","name":"Credit 2014.5.0.1","archived":true,"released":true,"releaseDate":"2014-06-28","userReleaseDate":"28/Jun/14","projectId":14501},{"self":"https://dbatlas.db.com/jira02/rest/api/2/version/37370","id":"37370","description":"Sybase replication technical release","name":"Credit 2014.5.1","archived":true,"released":true,"releaseDate":"2014-07-12","userReleaseDate":"12/Jul/14","projectId":14501},{"self":"https://dbatlas.db.com/jira02/rest/api/2/version/37417","id":"37417","description":"Regular dbmole release + DAP SSL certificate upgrade","name":"Credit 2014.5.2","archived":true,"released":true,"releaseDate":"2014-08-02","userReleaseDate":"02/Aug/14","projectId":14501},{"self":"https://dbatlas.db.com/jira02/rest/api/2/version/38620","id":"38620","description":"dbmole patch release on 9 Aug","name":"Credit 2014.5.2.1","archived":true,"released":true,"releaseDate":"2014-08-09","userReleaseDate":"09/Aug/14","projectId":14501},{"self":"https://dbatlas.db.com/jira02/rest/api/2/version/38041","id":"38041","description":"Counterpart.ISDA2014 flag in SDM","name":"Credit 2014.5.3","archived":true,"released":true,"releaseDate":"2014-08-16","userReleaseDate":"16/Aug/14","projectId":14501},{"self":"https://dbatlas.db.com/jira02/rest/api/2/version/37418","id":"37418","description":"Summit Consolidation: GBO sybase->oracle migration","name":"Credit 2014.5.4","archived":true,"released":true,"releaseDate":"2014-09-06","userReleaseDate":"06/Sep/14","projectId":14501},{"self":"https://dbatlas.db.com/jira02/rest/api/2/version/32143","id":"32143","description":"Candidates for 2014.6 Release","name":"Credit Candidates for 2014.6","archived":true,"released":true,"projectId":14501},{"self":"https://dbatlas.db.com/jira02/rest/api/2/version/32142","id":"32142","description":"2014.6 release (20-Sep-14)","name":"Credit 2014.6","archived":true,"released":true,"startDate":"2014-05-26","releaseDate":"2014-09-20","userStartDate":"26/May/14","userReleaseDate":"20/Sep/14","projectId":14501},{"self":"https://dbatlas.db.com/jira02/rest/api/2/version/39638","id":"39638","description":"urgent ISDA-related fix","name":"Credit 2014.6.1","archived":true,"released":true,"releaseDate":"2014-09-27","userReleaseDate":"27/Sep/14","projectId":14501},{"self":"https://dbatlas.db.com/jira02/rest/api/2/version/39639","id":"39639","description":"04 Oct release","name":"Credit 2014.6.2","archived":true,"released":true,"releaseDate":"2014-10-04","userReleaseDate":"04/Oct/14","projectId":14501},{"self":"https://dbatlas.db.com/jira02/rest/api/2/version/39982","id":"39982","description":"11 Oct release (support iCon CME SEF direct)","name":"Credit 2014.6.3","archived":true,"released":true,"releaseDate":"2014-10-11","userReleaseDate":"11/Oct/14","projectId":14501},{"self":"https://dbatlas.db.com/jira02/rest/api/2/version/40247","id":"40247","description":"01 Nov release (support iCon PB automation)","name":"Credit 2014.6.4","archived":true,"released":true,"releaseDate":"2014-11-01","userReleaseDate":"01/Nov/14","projectId":14501},{"self":"https://dbatlas.db.com/jira02/rest/api/2/version/36257","id":"36257","description":"Candidate for 2014.7 Release","name":"Credit Candidates for 2014.7","archived":true,"released":true,"projectId":14501},{"self":"https://dbatlas.db.com/jira02/rest/api/2/version/36256","id":"36256","description":"2014.7 release (08-Nov-14)","name":"Credit 2014.7","archived":true,"released":true,"releaseDate":"2014-11-15","userReleaseDate":"15/Nov/14","projectId":14501},{"self":"https://dbatlas.db.com/jira02/rest/api/2/version/39676","id":"39676","description":"Candidates for 2014.8 Release","name":"Credit Candidates for 2014.8","archived":true,"released":true,"projectId":14501},{"self":"https://dbatlas.db.com/jira02/rest/api/2/version/37924","id":"37924","description":"2014.8 release (06-Dec-14)","name":"Credit 2014.8","archived":true,"released":true,"releaseDate":"2014-12-06","userReleaseDate":"06/Dec/14","projectId":14501},{"self":"https://dbatlas.db.com/jira02/rest/api/2/version/22300","id":"22300","description":"BACKLOG of not prioritised/scheduled tasks","name":"Credit - BACKLOG","archived":false,"released":false,"projectId":14501},{"self":"https://dbatlas.db.com/jira02/rest/api/2/version/28112","id":"28112","description":"ARCHIVE container for closed/released items","name":"Credit - ARCHIVE","archived":false,"released":false,"releaseDate":"2018-01-09","overdue":false,"userReleaseDate":"09/Jan/18","projectId":14501},{"self":"https://dbatlas.db.com/jira02/rest/api/2/version/40556","id":"40556","description":"Candidates for 2015.1","name":"Credit Candidates for 2015.1","archived":true,"released":true,"projectId":14501},{"self":"https://dbatlas.db.com/jira02/rest/api/2/version/40709","id":"40709","description":"Candidates for 2015.2","name":"Credit Candidates for 2015.2","archived":true,"released":true,"releaseDate":"2015-02-28","userReleaseDate":"28/Feb/15","projectId":14501},{"self":"https://dbatlas.db.com/jira02/rest/api/2/version/40710","id":"40710","description":"Candidates for 2015.3","name":"Credit Candidates for 2015.3","archived":true,"released":true,"releaseDate":"2015-04-11","userReleaseDate":"11/Apr/15","projectId":14501},{"self":"https://dbatlas.db.com/jira02/rest/api/2/version/43202","id":"43202","description":"Credit Candidates for 2015.4","name":"Credit Candidates for 2015.4","archived":true,"released":false,"projectId":14501},{"self":"https://dbatlas.db.com/jira02/rest/api/2/version/43681","id":"43681","description":"Credit Candidates for 2015.5","name":"Credit Candidates for 2015.5","archived":true,"released":false,"projectId":14501},{"self":"https://dbatlas.db.com/jira02/rest/api/2/version/45029","id":"45029","description":"Credit Candidates for 2015.6","name":"Credit Candidates for 2015.6","archived":true,"released":true,"releaseDate":"2015-07-25","userReleaseDate":"25/Jul/15","projectId":14501},{"self":"https://dbatlas.db.com/jira02/rest/api/2/version/46514","id":"46514","description":"Credit Candidates for 2015.7","name":"Credit Candidates for 2015.7","archived":true,"released":false,"releaseDate":"2015-09-30","overdue":false,"userReleaseDate":"30/Sep/15","projectId":14501},{"self":"https://dbatlas.db.com/jira02/rest/api/2/version/48304","id":"48304","description":"Credit Candidates for 2015.8","name":"Credit Candidates for 2015.8","archived":true,"released":false,"releaseDate":"2015-11-21","overdue":false,"userReleaseDate":"21/Nov/15","projectId":14501},{"self":"https://dbatlas.db.com/jira02/rest/api/2/version/48305","id":"48305","description":"Credit Candidates for 2016.X","name":"Credit Candidates for 2016.X","archived":true,"released":false,"releaseDate":"2016-03-31","overdue":false,"userReleaseDate":"31/Mar/16","projectId":14501},{"self":"https://dbatlas.db.com/jira02/rest/api/2/version/40511","id":"40511","description":"2015.1 release (31-Jan-15)","name":"Credit 2015.1","archived":true,"released":true,"startDate":"2014-11-17","releaseDate":"2015-01-31","userStartDate":"17/Nov/14","userReleaseDate":"31/Jan/15","projectId":14501},{"self":"https://dbatlas.db.com/jira02/rest/api/2/version/42567","id":"42567","description":"2015.1.1 release (07-Feb-15)","name":"Credit 2015.1.1","archived":true,"released":true,"startDate":"2015-01-01","releaseDate":"2015-02-07","userStartDate":"01/Jan/15","userReleaseDate":"07/Feb/15","projectId":14501},{"self":"https://dbatlas.db.com/jira02/rest/api/2/version/43360","id":"43360","description":"Credit 2015.1.2 UI for backloading urgent improvements","name":"Credit 2015.1.2","archived":true,"released":true,"startDate":"2015-02-16","releaseDate":"2015-02-21","userStartDate":"16/Feb/15","userReleaseDate":"21/Feb/15","projectId":14501},{"self":"https://dbatlas.db.com/jira02/rest/api/2/version/39983","id":"39983","description":"2015.2 release (28-Feb-15)","name":"Credit 2015.2","archived":true,"released":true,"startDate":"2014-11-17","releaseDate":"2015-02-28","userStartDate":"17/Nov/14","userReleaseDate":"28/Feb/15","projectId":14501},{"self":"https://dbatlas.db.com/jira02/rest/api/2/version/43737","id":"43737","description":"Credit 2015.2.1","name":"Credit 2015.2.1","archived":true,"released":true,"releaseDate":"2015-03-28","userReleaseDate":"28/Mar/15","projectId":14501},{"self":"https://dbatlas.db.com/jira02/rest/api/2/version/44454","id":"44454","description":"Credit 2015.2.2 QlickView 2003 to 2008 migration","name":"Credit 2015.2.2","archived":true,"released":true,"startDate":"2015-02-01","releaseDate":"2015-04-04","userStartDate":"01/Feb/15","userReleaseDate":"04/Apr/15","projectId":14501},{"self":"https://dbatlas.db.com/jira02/rest/api/2/version/40708","id":"40708","description":"2015.3 release (18-Apr-15)","name":"Credit 2015.3","archived":true,"released":true,"releaseDate":"2015-04-17","userReleaseDate":"17/Apr/15","projectId":14501},{"self":"https://dbatlas.db.com/jira02/rest/api/2/version/44940","id":"44940","description":"Credit 2015.3.1 Mandatory patching","name":"Credit 2015.3.1","archived":true,"released":true,"startDate":"2015-04-13","releaseDate":"2015-04-25","userStartDate":"13/Apr/15","userReleaseDate":"25/Apr/15","projectId":14501},{"self":"https://dbatlas.db.com/jira02/rest/api/2/version/44950","id":"44950","description":"Credit 2015.3.2 MW enabling","name":"Credit 2015.3.2","archived":true,"released":true,"releaseDate":"2015-05-02","userReleaseDate":"02/May/15","projectId":14501},{"self":"https://dbatlas.db.com/jira02/rest/api/2/version/43201","id":"43201","description":"Credit 2015.4 (4-July-2015)","name":"Credit 2015.4","archived":true,"released":true,"startDate":"2015-03-02","releaseDate":"2015-07-04","userStartDate":"02/Mar/15","userReleaseDate":"04/Jul/15","projectId":14501},{"self":"https://dbatlas.db.com/jira02/rest/api/2/version/43680","id":"43680","description":"Credit 2015.5 (11-July-2015)","name":"Credit 2015.5","archived":true,"released":true,"releaseDate":"2015-07-11","userReleaseDate":"11/Jul/15","projectId":14501},{"self":"https://dbatlas.db.com/jira02/rest/api/2/version/47226","id":"47226","description":"Passwords Reset","name":"Credit 2015.5.1","archived":true,"released":true,"releaseDate":"2015-07-25","userReleaseDate":"25/Jul/15","projectId":14501},{"self":"https://dbatlas.db.com/jira02/rest/api/2/version/44710","id":"44710","description":"Credit 2015.6 (15-Aug-2015)","name":"Credit 2015.6","archived":true,"released":true,"releaseDate":"2015-08-15","userReleaseDate":"15/Aug/15","projectId":14501},{"self":"https://dbatlas.db.com/jira02/rest/api/2/version/49021","id":"49021","description":"Credit 2015.6.1 EMPIRE minor + TMP","name":"Credit 2015.6.1","archived":true,"released":false,"releaseDate":"2015-09-05","overdue":false,"userReleaseDate":"05/Sep/15","projectId":14501},{"self":"https://dbatlas.db.com/jira02/rest/api/2/version/45030","id":"45030","description":"Credit 2015.7","name":"Credit 2015.7","archived":true,"released":true,"releaseDate":"2015-09-26","userReleaseDate":"26/Sep/15","projectId":14501},{"self":"https://dbatlas.db.com/jira02/rest/api/2/version/50316","id":"50316","description":"DB sp135 + 3ds","name":"Credit 2015.7.0.1","archived":true,"released":true,"startDate":"2015-10-03","releaseDate":"2015-10-03","userStartDate":"03/Oct/15","userReleaseDate":"03/Oct/15","projectId":14501},{"self":"https://dbatlas.db.com/jira02/rest/api/2/version/50527","id":"50527","description":"DB sp135","name":"Credit 2015.7.0.2","archived":true,"released":true,"startDate":"2015-10-05","releaseDate":"2015-10-17","userStartDate":"05/Oct/15","userReleaseDate":"17/Oct/15","projectId":14501},{"self":"https://dbatlas.db.com/jira02/rest/api/2/version/48518","id":"48518","description":"Credit 2015.7.1 Database","name":"Credit 2015.7.1","archived":true,"released":true,"releaseDate":"2015-10-17","userReleaseDate":"17/Oct/15","projectId":14501},{"self":"https://dbatlas.db.com/jira02/rest/api/2/version/49271","id":"49271","description":"Credit 2015.7.2 ASPAC Summit","name":"Credit 2015.7.2","archived":true,"released":true,"releaseDate":"2015-11-07","userReleaseDate":"07/Nov/15","projectId":14501},{"self":"https://dbatlas.db.com/jira02/rest/api/2/version/50667","id":"50667","description":"Tech Release","name":"Credit 2015.7.3","archived":true,"released":true,"releaseDate":"2015-11-14","userReleaseDate":"14/Nov/15","projectId":14501},{"self":"https://dbatlas.db.com/jira02/rest/api/2/version/48060","id":"48060","description":"Credit 2015.8","name":"Credit 2015.8","archived":true,"released":true,"releaseDate":"2015-11-21","userReleaseDate":"21/Nov/15","projectId":14501},{"self":"https://dbatlas.db.com/jira02/rest/api/2/version/51616","id":"51616","description":"get rid of Tomcat","name":"Credit 2015.8.0.1","archived":true,"released":true,"startDate":"2015-11-16","releaseDate":"2015-11-28","userStartDate":"16/Nov/15","userReleaseDate":"28/Nov/15","projectId":14501},{"self":"https://dbatlas.db.com/jira02/rest/api/2/version/51003","id":"51003","description":"CREDIT-8906","name":"Credit 2015.8.1","archived":true,"released":true,"startDate":"2015-11-10","releaseDate":"2015-12-05","userStartDate":"10/Nov/15","userReleaseDate":"05/Dec/15","projectId":14501},{"self":"https://dbatlas.db.com/jira02/rest/api/2/version/51615","id":"51615","description":"TPSLIII-1000 related","name":"Credit 2016.0.1","archived":true,"released":true,"startDate":"2015-11-23","releaseDate":"2016-01-30","userStartDate":"23/Nov/15","userReleaseDate":"30/Jan/16","projectId":14501},{"self":"https://dbatlas.db.com/jira02/rest/api/2/version/52824","id":"52824","name":"Credit 2016.0.2","archived":true,"released":true,"releaseDate":"2016-02-13","userReleaseDate":"13/Feb/16","projectId":14501},{"self":"https://dbatlas.db.com/jira02/rest/api/2/version/53185","id":"53185","description":"Summit Related release","name":"Credit 2016.0.3","archived":true,"released":true,"startDate":"2016-01-11","releaseDate":"2016-02-27","userStartDate":"11/Jan/16","userReleaseDate":"27/Feb/16","projectId":14501},{"self":"https://dbatlas.db.com/jira02/rest/api/2/version/54760","id":"54760","description":"3dstatic fix","name":"Credit 2016.0.3.1","archived":true,"released":true,"startDate":"2016-03-04","releaseDate":"2016-03-12","userStartDate":"04/Mar/16","userReleaseDate":"12/Mar/16","projectId":14501},{"self":"https://dbatlas.db.com/jira02/rest/api/2/version/53439","id":"53439","description":"Database related / paragon","name":"Credit 2016.0.4","archived":true,"released":true,"startDate":"2016-01-25","releaseDate":"2016-03-19","userStartDate":"25/Jan/16","userReleaseDate":"19/Mar/16","projectId":14501},{"self":"https://dbatlas.db.com/jira02/rest/api/2/version/48303","id":"48303","description":"Credit 2016.1","name":"Credit 2016.1","archived":true,"released":true,"releaseDate":"2016-04-09","userReleaseDate":"09/Apr/16","projectId":14501},{"self":"https://dbatlas.db.com/jira02/rest/api/2/version/46225","id":"46225","description":"BACKLOG - Prod Bug Fixes of all the items that requir Dev involvment","name":"BACKLOG - Prod Bug Fixes","archived":false,"released":false,"releaseDate":"2017-09-30","overdue":false,"userReleaseDate":"30/Sep/17","projectId":14501},{"self":"https://dbatlas.db.com/jira02/rest/api/2/version/46515","id":"46515","description":"BACKLOG - ITAO","name":"BACKLOG - ITAO","archived":false,"released":false,"releaseDate":"2017-06-16","overdue":false,"userReleaseDate":"16/Jun/17","projectId":14501},{"self":"https://dbatlas.db.com/jira02/rest/api/2/version/49459","id":"49459","description":"BACKLOG - DevOps","name":"BACKLOG - DevOps","archived":false,"released":false,"releaseDate":"2017-09-01","overdue":false,"userReleaseDate":"01/Sep/17","projectId":14501},{"self":"https://dbatlas.db.com/jira02/rest/api/2/version/51968","id":"51968","description":"Product Backlog","name":"Product Backlog","archived":false,"released":false,"releaseDate":"2020-06-09","overdue":false,"userReleaseDate":"09/Jun/20","projectId":14501},{"self":"https://dbatlas.db.com/jira02/rest/api/2/version/55760","id":"55760","description":"UCD for 3dsf","name":"Ciredit 2016.1.1","archived":true,"released":true,"startDate":"2016-04-11","releaseDate":"2016-04-30","userStartDate":"11/Apr/16","userReleaseDate":"30/Apr/16","projectId":14501},{"self":"https://dbatlas.db.com/jira02/rest/api/2/version/55812","id":"55812","description":"Hot fix for 3dstatic","name":"Credit 2016.1.0.1","archived":true,"released":true,"startDate":"2016-04-11","releaseDate":"2016-04-16","userStartDate":"11/Apr/16","userReleaseDate":"16/Apr/16","projectId":14501},{"self":"https://dbatlas.db.com/jira02/rest/api/2/version/58143","id":"58143","description":"Windsor-Major","name":"Credit 2016.4","archived":false,"released":false,"startDate":"2016-08-31","releaseDate":"2016-11-12","overdue":false,"userStartDate":"31/Aug/16","userReleaseDate":"12/Nov/16","projectId":14501},{"self":"https://dbatlas.db.com/jira02/rest/api/2/version/50131","id":"50131","description":"Sandown - Major release","name":"Credit 2016.3","archived":false,"released":false,"startDate":"2016-03-15","releaseDate":"2016-09-03","overdue":false,"userStartDate":"15/Mar/16","userReleaseDate":"03/Sep/16","projectId":14501},{"self":"https://dbatlas.db.com/jira02/rest/api/2/version/55260","id":"55260","description":"Newmarket - Major","name":"Credit 2016.2.1","archived":false,"released":false,"startDate":"2016-03-18","releaseDate":"2016-07-16","overdue":false,"userStartDate":"18/Mar/16","userReleaseDate":"16/Jul/16","projectId":14501},{"self":"https://dbatlas.db.com/jira02/rest/api/2/version/49890","id":"49890","description":"Kempton - Major","name":"Credit 2016.2","archived":true,"released":true,"startDate":"2016-02-19","releaseDate":"2016-06-11","userStartDate":"19/Feb/16","userReleaseDate":"11/Jun/16","projectId":14501},{"self":"https://dbatlas.db.com/jira02/rest/api/2/version/54286","id":"54286","description":"Nucleus for dbMole and CEM","name":"Credit 2016.2.0.1","archived":false,"released":false,"startDate":"2016-02-01","releaseDate":"2016-07-02","overdue":false,"userStartDate":"01/Feb/16","userReleaseDate":"02/Jul/16","projectId":14501},{"self":"https://dbatlas.db.com/jira02/rest/api/2/version/58381","id":"58381","description":"Towcester - Major release","name":"Credit 2016.3.1","archived":false,"released":false,"startDate":"2016-07-01","releaseDate":"2016-10-15","overdue":false,"userStartDate":"01/Jul/16","userReleaseDate":"15/Oct/16","projectId":14501},{"self":"https://dbatlas.db.com/jira02/rest/api/2/version/58771","id":"58771","description":"Plumpton - Minor release","name":"Credit 2016.2.2","archived":false,"released":false,"startDate":"2016-06-01","releaseDate":"2016-08-13","overdue":false,"userStartDate":"01/Jun/16","userReleaseDate":"13/Aug/16","projectId":14501},{"self":"https://dbatlas.db.com/jira02/rest/api/2/version/58775","id":"58775","description":"York - Minor","name":"Credit 2016.4.1","archived":false,"released":false,"startDate":"2016-09-30","releaseDate":"2016-12-10","overdue":false,"userStartDate":"30/Sep/16","userReleaseDate":"10/Dec/16","projectId":14501},{"self":"https://dbatlas.db.com/jira02/rest/api/2/version/59569","id":"59569","name":"2016.1","archived":false,"released":false,"projectId":14501}]
at org.codehaus.jettison.json.JSONTokener.syntaxError(JSONTokener.java:448)
at org.codehaus.jettison.json.JSONObject.<init>(JSONObject.java:178)
at org.codehaus.jettison.json.JSONObject.<init>(JSONObject.java:275)
at com.atlassian.jira.rest.client.internal.async.AbstractAsynchronousRestClient$1.handle(AbstractAsynchronousRestClient.java:138)
at com.atlassian.jira.rest.client.internal.async.AbstractAsynchronousRestClient$3.apply(AbstractAsynchronousRestClient.java:179)
... 26 more
```

And if you follow the line where is showing me the reason, is returning me the JSONArray that I need to get in order to achieve my goal.
So, the real question is how do I get that JSONArray in order to be able to parse it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your are not loged in with your account , and you have to have Access to see thouse Projects , or to make requests on them

Answer (score 0):

The problem was because I didn't had an connection with a user wich have permission to get the versions for a specified Jira Project.